# Firebase - is a new Registration Token needed for each platform of an app ( e.g. android + web ) that a single user uses?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, web, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Is a new Registration Token needed for every platform of an app that a user uses?**

For example, I login to Facebook from my phone's app and I also access it from the web. Would this require a single Registration token, shared by the different platforms, or would every platform still require its individual Registration token for a given user. Hence, a user may have multiple Registration tokens being used at the same time if they access the app from several different platforms?

P.S. I am specifically asking the question in reference to cloud messaging where a notification is generated and I want to notify the user on all platforms they are on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have both a web app and a native app for a platform, and a user uses both from a single device, those two apps will have different registration tokens. The registration token is for the *application* instance, and each app (web/native) is a separate application instance.